# Hide particular parameter in URL along with value

Tags: .htaccess

I have URLs like 
`www.website.com/url?booking_id=1234`

I need to hide the booking_id along with the value using htaccess.. So that, the URL will be like `www.website.com/url`

I've tried this rule, but it is not working

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ /$1? [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle for simple understanding

Comment: Hide how? What should the end URL be?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I need to hide the booking_id parameter along with it's value and`www.website.com/url` should be the URL.

Comment: @hjpotter92 did u check this?

Comment: @anubhava can u please help me with this